Electromagnetic momentum in electric charges
While reading I come across  one notes. Related to electric charges, apart from momentum which arises due to the mass of particle there is another momentum called electromagnetic momentum. What is this electromagnetic momentum?
The note also says Newton's third law fails with respect to electric charge. Why is it so?

Newton's third law fails with respect to electric charge No, it does not. Momentum is always conserved. For the first part of your question, the EM field carries momentum. For example, see this PSE post.

@josephh there is Griffith's note in his book about how the conservation of momentum is still conserved in electromagnetism but there are some situations where newton's third law between two particles doesn't hold (some momentum goes to the fields). I think this is not entirely a consensus among physicists but I did see it mentioned in some serious books about EM theory

@josephh It is true momentum is conserved due to momentum in the EM field, but Newton's third law does not hold for EM forces between two (or more) particles.

@JánLalinský I highly doubt that the OP was thinking about non-reciprocal interactions you are citing (and even that argument is a little tenuous and applies to specific examples). On the contrary. The OP apppears to be thinking that Newton's third law is broken for electrostatic charges, which is not true. Though it's also possible I misinterpreted his question.

@OfekGillon See my comment to Jan.

@josephh why do you doubt that? They mention EM momentum, which exists when charges are moving, and then EM forces do not obey 3rd law. 3rd law is obeyed only by electric forces in electrostatics, where EM momentum does not play role.

@JánLalinský 3rd law is obeyed only by electric forces in electrostatics, where EM momentum does not play role That's what I said.
